# How to reach an index-seek on nullable columns?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan

Let's assume the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (V1 INT NULL, V2 INT NOT NULL)
CREATE INDEX niFooV1V2 ON Foo(V1, V2)
DECLARE @searchForV1 INT = NULL
DECLARE @searchForV2 INT = 0
```

How can I write a query that uses the index to find all rows with the specified value of V1 and V2?

Basically, there is an index for exactly that and it should be possible to find all rows with a single seek. But whatever I try, SqlServer does never use both columns of the index.

e.g. I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WITH(FORCESEEK) WHERE ((V1 IS NULL AND @searchForV1 IS NULL) OR (V1 IS NOT NULL AND @searchForV1 IS NOT NULL AND @searchForV1 = V1)) AND V2 = @searchForV2
```

In the execution-plan, it executes two independent index-seeks for V1 (one for null and one for non-null) and applies a filter for V2 after this. In my case, the first index-seeks return about 100.000 rows that are then scanned for V2 to reduce the result to 100 rows. This is not really efficient.

Another way of solving this might be an IF-Else-Construct, where I write two independent queries depending on whether @searchForV1 is NULL or NOT NULL. But this seems very awkward...

Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that SqlServer is just a bit stupid here.

The issue is the filter-condition I used:

```
((V1 IS NULL AND @searchForV1 IS NULL) OR (V1 IS NOT NULL AND @searchForV1 IS NOT NULL AND @searchForV1 = V1))
```

If you remove the both "IS NOT NULL"-checks, the index-seek works perfectly fine:

```
((V1 IS NULL AND @searchForV1 IS NULL) OR @searchForV1 = V1)
```

While both checks are semantically equivalent, SqlServer uses an index-seek only in the latter case. When writing the code, I just added both "IS NOT NULL"-checks to be on the safe side, since unknown-results that come from comparing a null-value to a non-null-value do often cause problems when negating the whole thing.

Thank's to Dan for making me check this.

Comment: you beat me to it.  I agree SQL Server could be smarter about eliminating the redundant predicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the index column order and remove the FORCESEEK hint:

```
CREATE INDEX dbo.niFooV2V1 ON Foo(V2, V1);

SELECT  *
FROM    Foo
WHERE   ( ( V1 IS NULL
            AND @searchForV1 IS NULL
          )
          OR ( V1 IS NOT NULL
               AND @searchForV1 IS NOT NULL
               AND @searchForV1 = V1
             )
        )
        AND V2 = @searchForV2;
```

This index will allow an index seek on the V2 equality predicate.  The first columns of an index should specify equality predicates used in queries with the most selective columns first.

Not that it matters from a performance perspective but the query can be simplified as below since the V1 and @searchForV1 IS NULL conditions are redundant due to the equal condition.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Foo
WHERE   ( ( V1 IS NULL
            AND @searchForV1 IS NULL
          )
          OR @searchForV1 = V1
        )
        AND V2 = @searchForV2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's a nice workaround, but will fail as soon as both columns are nullable.